# How Core Data save NSNnumber data without rounding the decimal part in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, formatter

I am trying to save decimal number to the core data `NSNumber` object but decimal value had saved with rounding digits when  we enter a 5 digit number with its decimal part.

If I enter up to 9999,999 getting save same value to database but in case of a 5 digit (e.g.,10000.999) it will be save as 10001 in the database.

```
chargeFloat=10000.999;
 value.fees      = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:chargeFloat];//value is an entity object
                                                          //fees is nsnumber
```

but in database showing this value as `10001`.

I need a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Floats give you 6 to 9 significant digits, *doubles* give you 15 to 17 significant digits and *NSDecimal* gives you 38 significant digits. I suggest that you either use doubles of NSDecimals.